# Is there any systematic relationship between the three classes of badges within one category?

Tags: discussion, badges

I understand that the three classes of badges (i.e. Gold, Silver, and Bronze) are applied to all badge categories (e.g. Question badges or Answer Badges, etc..).

I also understand that within, for example, the category of "Answer Badges":

1. A "gold badge" is awarded when: *Answer score is of 100 or more*,
2. A "silver badge" is awarded when: *Answer score is of 25 or more*..
3. A "bronze badge" is awarded when: *Answer score is of 10 or
   more*

However, in other cases it was not in the same uniform.

Is there any systematic rule (e.g. *10, *50, *100, ...) between the three classes when they are awarded, that apply to all the many different badge categories (e.g. participation badges, moderation badges, ...)?

Comment: This is lost in the fog of time, but it is probably fair to assume that they used existing data to find out what the proper ratio should be.  Particularly data collected during the beta period.  And sure, it increases quickly for answers since a popular answer draws a proportionally large increment of votes because more people look at it.  Same mechanism doesn't apply for, say, Epic vs Legendary.  There hasn't been a lot of debate about it so they got it about right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The systematic rule is that the low-level badge is bronze, the intermediate badge is silver, and the highest level badge is gold. Like the [badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) says:

> **Bronze badges** encourage users to try out new features on the site. They are easy to get if you try!
>
> **Silver badges** are less common than bronze ones. You'll need to plan your strategy to get one of these.
>
> **Gold badges** recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.

There are otherwise no fixed number thresholds associated with each type of metal.

Someone just made the arbitrary determination of what actions should be sufficient to earn a badge, based on knowledge of how the system works, empirical data of how many people have done these things, and the types of goals that they want to encourage users to set and/or behaviors that they want to encourage.